# Run a piece of code several times changing certain parameters in R (like a macro in SAS)

Tags: r

Trying to learn the ropes in R and already struggling trying to find a replacement for SAS macro.

I'm trying to run a piece of code several times, but I'm having a hard time and came here for help.

First, I'm working with this example file, with a variable that gives me the quantity of rows that I have previously analised in another file (qtde_registros), followed by three variables that give me the quantity of rows that had different type of errors.

```
    file <- readRDS(file="file.Rda")
    file
    
      qtde_registros error1 error2 error3
    1           1175      0      0      0
```

After that, I created a list with the errors and another one with the description of each one of them.
Then, using those lists and the file mentioned initially, I wish to create several files (one for each error) that will later be binded in one last file to form a final report.

As I said, I'm struggling with it, so I made an example code of how it would be forming the first file:

```
error_list <- list("Error1","Error2","Error3",)

description_list <- list("Code not found",
                        "Invalid date.",
                        "Negative value.")

error1 <- file
error1$file_name <- "Clients"
error1$error <- error_list[1]
error1$qtde <- error1$error1
error1$desc <- description_list[1]
error1 <- select(error1, file_name, error, qtde, desc)
error1

  file_name  error qtde           desc 
1   Clients Error1    0 Code not found
```

And that leads to my question: how can I make the code above run several times, one for each erros on my list?

I'm aware that the whole mentality may not be the best, as the approach to do certain things are different depending on the language used, but I have to work with the knowledge I have at the moment.

I'm thinking of using the apply family of functions, but I didn't managed to work it out.

Thanks in advance for the help and sorry for any errors in typing or grammar (english is not my first language).

EDIT: forgot to say that I'm not intend to do via For or While loop.

Comment: It looks like a complicated lookup code, would a factor make a bit more sense here? You can very roughly think of a factor as a SAS format.

Comment: Can't say I am familiar to the concept of factor. I'll look it up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In R (and many other languages) you'll be using a form of [`for-loop`](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2015/12/how-to-write-the-first-for-loop-in-r/). In R there are several wrappers for loops with specific outcome in the `*apply` family. Here's a short (incomplete) list of the `*apply` family and their input/output:

- `lapply` -> list output
- `sapply` -> List or atomic (integer vector, numeric vector etc.)
- `mapply` -> Similar to `sapply` but can take more than 1 input to go over (so if you have 2 simultanious things to loop over for example)
- `tapply` -> loop over groups defined by `INDEX`
- `apply` -> Loop over an array (either rows or columns) return matrix/vector

And so on.

I am guessing that your example is incomplete, but I'll show 3 examples to get you started. One using a `for-loop`, one using `lapply` and one using `mapply`.

## `for-loop`

A for-loop is the classic method (found in most programming languages). It works by having a `for(---)` where `---` is replaced by something to iterate over. This could be `error_list` or it could be a numeric vector `seq(1, n)` or `1:n`. Here you have more than 1 thing to iterate over, so a numeric vector makes sense (and we use this to subset the data)

```
errors <- list() # <== Somewhere to put our results
for(i in 1:length(error_list)){
  error_i <- list(file = file, 
                  file_name = "Clients",
                  error = error_list[[i]], # Use i to subset error_list
                  qtde = error_list[[i]], # Maybe this should be something else in your case
                  desc = description_list[[i]]
                  )
  # Put into our errors list. Create "error1" using paste and our index
  errors[[paste0('error', i)]] <- error_i 
}
```

And by the end all of your results will be in the `errors` list to be extracted using `errors[1]` or `errors["errors1"]` (change the number to your error). This can then be combined using `do.call(rbind, errors)` and then saved using `write.table` (or `write.csv` or similar).

## `lapply`

For the `*apply` family, the `*apply` takes care of the looping. But instead we have to provide a function to execute (a macro in SAS terms) in each iteration. So we wrap the contents of the loop in the function above.

```
macro <- function(i){
 list(file = file, 
      file_name = "Clients",
      error = error_list[[i]], # Use i to subset error_list
      qtde = error_list[[i]], # Maybe this should be something else in your case?
      desc = description_list[[i]]
      )
}
errors <- lapply(1:length(error_list), macro)
#set names afterwards
names(errors) <- paste0("error", 1:length(error_list))
```

And once again we have the data ready to be extracted saved etc. This is equivalent to:

```
errors <- list()
for(i in 1:length(error_list))
  errors[[i]] <- macro(i)
names(errors) <- paste0("error", 1:length(error_list))
```

## `mapply`

Now in your case you have more than 1 thing to iterate over. An alternative is to use `mapply` and add these as parameters to your function instead. This way we remove `error_list[[i]]` and `description_list[[i]]` from the function and instead add these as parameters

```
macro_mapply <- function(error, description){
 list(file = file, 
      file_name = "Clients",
      error = error, # No need to use I here anymore
      qtde = error, # Maybe this should be something else in your case?
      desc = description
      )
}
errors <- mapply(macro_mapply, 
                 # parameters to iterate over comes after function
                 error = error_list, 
                 description = description_list,
                 # Avoid simplification (if we want a list returned)
                 SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
names(errors) <- paste0("error", 1:length(error_list))
```

Note that "mapply" will try to return a vector if possible, so I set `SIMPLIFY = FALSE` to avoid this.

## Things to note:

In the above 3 examples I have not taken into account if you read multiple `file`s, or any other parameters changing. So if you have to read a file in each iteration it will make sense to go with the first 2 examples and add `readRDS` to the loop or function with appropriate file naming. Also I have used your data, but I am guessing `qtde` and `error` should be different in your specific case but this is not clear from your example.

I hope this will help getting you started.

Once you've gotten the hang of your first loops I and somewhat understand how `*apply`s work, I would then suggest checking out [`tidyverse`](https://www.tidyverse.org/) which provides what many find to be a more "user-friendly" and intuitive interface to data transformation.

I hope that this will help you getting started on solving your problem.

Comment: This is a phenomenal answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response and help. While I was not able to use it in the way that I intended, it gave me a north. From your repply and reading again how I put it, I may have not expressed everything I wanted correctly. In the end, I wanted an data frame with the columns descripted in the end of my examplo. But using your solution, I was able to retrive all the results on a list. Just have to figure it out how to properly use it. When I'm able, I will try to post here again with my progress and maybe new questions.

Comment: NOTE: Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

Comment: Another 10 points have been granted to you. ;-)

Comment: That's true. Now I was able to upvote it. Thanks.